# How to obtain the determinant of the difference of two matrices?

Tags: determinants

I am trying to obtain the determinant of the difference between the identity matrix and an A matrix. The question is such:

```
                            det(I-A) or another one is, det(I-AB)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are you expecting? A magic formula where none exists?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: I wonder how one can know that a formula does not exist. Anyway, the OP is not a research level question.

Comment: $\det(I-A)=1-\mathrm{Tr}(A)+\mathrm{Tr}(\wedge^2A)+\ldots $ - but I agree this is not a question at research level.

Comment: @Taladris: I wonder how one can know this is not a research level question. There are examples of complicated determinants which count interesting quantities such as plane partitions with particular symmetries which can be expressed as $Det(A\pm I)$ where $A$ does not seem complicated, but where finding the characteristic polynomial of $A$ does not seem easy.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\det(A+ tI) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k^n(A).t^{n-k}, \qquad
c^n_k(A) = \text{Trace}\Big(\bigwedge^k A: \bigwedge^k\mathbb R^n\to \bigwedge^k\mathbb R^n\Big).
$$

Comment: What's $\wedge $?

Comment: @Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen: It's an exterior power, more commonly denoted as abx did in the comments with ${\bigwedge}^k$. The overset $k$ in display mode is for an AND operator. Anyway, a linear map on a vectorspace induces a multilinear map on the space of alternating $k$-forms on that vectorspace, a component of the exterior algebra. You can coordinatize it using the dimension-$k$ minors of a matrix.